# When should the return of a React hook be passed as a property instead of re-calling the hook?

Tags: react-hooks

It seems that some React "read only?" hooks are designed to be called from multiple different places to return the same information, e.g.

```
const myTheme = useTheme()   // From @mui/material
const myApp = useApp()       // From MongoDB Realm
```

In these cases it's conventient to call them directly within a deep child, rather than pass `myTheme` or `myApp` all the way down.

However, if a custom "read-write?" hook has a state that can be updated within it, e.g.

```
const myToDos = useToDos()
```

this should typically only be called once for the application (or per user, etc), otherwise you'll end up with multiple copies of the internal state which could be updated independently.

Is there a convention to know which hooks are safe to call from multiple places, and which you can only call once, passing the result down to children?

My question stems from a debug trail where I discovered I accidentally had two copies of an internal state because I'd called a custom hook twice from different places - which took me a long time to discover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly it seems your question boils down to something more like knowing when a React hook returns a stable "global" value, or if they return localized "instance" values.

React hooks that return a value from some global "context", e.g. React context, Redux, etc, then generally each instantiation of the hook returns the same global value. The state and logic reside in a single location, e.g. typically a Provider component higher up the ReactTree, and are exposed out via hooks that all reference the same "thing".

React hooks that return localized "instance" values, e.g. `useState`, `useForm` hook from `redux-hook-form`, etc, all have internal state and logic for the purpose of being used individually/independently in local components, sometimes even in multiples.

They each have their valid use cases, so choose the implementation you need for the specific use case you have.

If your question is more about coming across some random React hook, there's no way to tell just from the hook call what use case it is fulfilling, you'll need to look up its documentation or look in the source code to see what it does.

Comment: Another indicator is that if there's a Provider that works with the hook, it's usually global state.

Comment: Thanks @Drew for the detailed answer. It's confirmed that I'm not misunderstanding either use case, and that I just need to be careful when using localized instance value hooks to not create the hook twice.